# Conditional Decimal Format

Tags: excel, formatting

I want to format a number with two decimals unless it's `0`.  Can I do this?

```
123.93
 23.00
144.34
     0
  2.38
```

Answer (score 5):

This works great:

Go to format cells and select custom. Then paste  this 0.00;[=0]0 into the Type field

from http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/CustomFormats.htm

Comment: You mean 0.00;[=0]0 -- Otherwise, a very nice answer!

Comment: Excel number formatting drives me MAD. There is no simple solution to many common problems. Example: maximum X number of decimal places with no trailing zeroes, and no decimal for whole numbers. You HAVE to use conditional formatting. So incredibly stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

=IF(A1=0,"0",TEXT(A1,"0.00"))

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that includes a separator for thousands, shows negative values in red font and aligns zeros with whole numbers:

```
#,##0.00;[Red]-#,##0.00;0
```

(for the alignment, there are three blanks at the end).

Answer (score 0):

**From Excel Help:**

> A number format can have up to four sections of code, separated by
>   semicolons. These code sections define the format for positive
>   numbers, negative numbers, zero values, and text, in that order.
>
> ;;;

So All you really need to do is something like  `0.00,-0.00,0`